# get input type file val with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dhtml

I am trying to write an mulitple image upload script...I'm stuck on part where javascript sends the dataStrings to the php script. So problem is that nothing is going to be inserted in database, the php script is working fine, therefore I'm not goona post it here.

Example...

HTML Code:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<div id="list"></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(".update_button").click(function() 
{
  var imgval = $('#files').val();
  var updateval = $("#update").val();
  var dataString = 'update='+ updateval+'&img='+ imgval;

    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('Loading Update...');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "wall-message_ajax.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: What is going wrong? What is the expected result and the actual result? Are there any errors logged in the error console? Why doesn't the AJAX request have an error handler or non-trivial success handler in order to examine the results better?

Comment: There is no result, as I mentioned above, I have to much errors in console, so I can't filter them...

Comment: dataString has wrong data.. console.log it

Comment: Are you sure...var dataString = 'update='+ updateval+'&img='+ imgval;

Comment: It works with single file, but multiple is a problem...

Comment: If you have so many errors in your console that you can't even filter through them, that's definitely the place to start. We can't help you fix an error we don't know about. Post them here or debug things and slim it down.

Comment: I have no errors in my console expect some css errors.

Comment: How can I acces all the files list when multiple files have selected?

Comment: maybe the input type file has no value...

Comment: I already solved the problem, there was a problem in a if clause...